# Java - Guardar Información en JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Como puedo guardar datos de una **JTable** sin pasarlos a otra, he leído y veo que para hacer esto los datos se pasan a otra **JTable**, pero queria saber si es posible mantenerlos guardados para despues utilizarlos, me sería de mucha ayuda.

Ahora lo que hago es guardarla como atributo de una clase, aunque no se si de esta manera se pueda.

```
public class Pedido { 
  public String mesa; 
  public JTable plato;
  public Pedido link;

  public Pedido(String mesa, JTable plato) { 
       this.mesa = mesa; 
       this.plato = plato;
       this.link = null; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Debe agregar mas informacion, el codigo que ha intentado, lo que lleva hecho. Asi sera mas facil ayudarle

Comment: Lo que yo intenté es guardar la Jtable como atributo de una clase pero al momento de mostrarla no salía nada. `Pedido q = new Pedido(mesa, table);`

Comment: Lo que tengo que hacer es algo que simule a un restaurante y yo queria intentar guardar las ordenes que se mostraban por pantalla en una jtable en esa misma jtable.

Comment: Es posible que agregue la clase de java donde tiene el inconveniente ?

Comment: `public class Pedido {
    public String mesa;
    public JTable plato;
    public Pedido link;

    public Pedido(String mesa, JTable plato) {
        this.mesa = mesa;
        this.plato = plato;
        this.link = null;
    }
    
}`

Comment: Soy nuevo aqui y no se muy bien como funciona de los comentarios asi que mis disculpas, en el tema la clase es una clase normal con sus atributos y su constructor no hago nada mas en ella.

Comment: Puedes [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/58141/edit) tu pregunta, para asi agregar el codigo

Comment: @IvanBotero No se me había ocurrido, gracias

Comment: He votado a tu pregunta +1 ya que eres nuevo, bienvenido a StackOverflow amigo :) Espero te agrade el sitio, si quisieras saber como hacer preguntas o dudas puedes realizar un pequeño tour por la pagina: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour , o ir directamente al centro de ayuda: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help . Si quieres hacer preguntas a la comunidad como tal, quejas, inconcordancias, o ideas, puedes ir a la pagina meta del sitio: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/ :))) Nuevamente bienvenido.

Comment: Quieres guardar la información de la tabla aunque cierres el programa?

Comment: @FrEqDe Eso si sabría como hacerlo, por ahora lo que me interesa es guardarla temporalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing esta **ligeramente** basado en un patrón de MVC, así para las vistas (como `JTable` o `JList`) existen modelos (en el caso de `JTable` las interfaces [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) y [`TableColumnModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html)).

La clase `JTable` viene con constructores que permiten de instarlos por ejemplo como

- `new JTable(tableModel);` (con tableColumnModel por defecto) o
- `new JTable(tableModel, tableColumnModel);`

Para guardar tus datos separados de la JTable que los visualiza, implementa `TableModel` en un modelo propio:

```
public MiModelo implements TableModel{
    // ... implementa todos los métodos de la interfaz
}
```

Luego de eso puedes instar un modelo de esta clase, y puedes instar cualquier `JTable` que quieres con los datos agregados a tu modelo.

Te recomiendo de estudiar estas dos interfaces y tratar de entender sus métodos y sus usos. Así logras en separar la capa de vista de la capa de modelo de datos.